# Sufficient conditions for $\mathbb{Q} (\alpha , \beta )=\mathbb{Q} (\alpha +c\beta ) \forall c\in \mathbb{Q}^*$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

What are some sufficient conditions for $\mathbb{Q} (\alpha , \beta )=\mathbb{Q} (\alpha +c\beta ) \forall c\in \mathbb{Q}^*$ with $\alpha , \beta $ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

We know that, for example,

> $[\mathbb{Q} (\alpha ):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q} (\beta ):\mathbb{Q}]=2
> \wedge\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\neq\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ is a sufficient condition.

We can prove it by adapting the proof of the existence of the primitive element.

*Proof.* Let $\sigma _1,...,\sigma _4$ the be the elements of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)/\mathbb{Q})\cong C_2\times C_2 $. Then the polynomial $$p(x)=\Pi_{i<j}(\sigma_i(\alpha)+x\sigma _j(\beta)-\sigma_j(\alpha)-x\sigma_j(\beta))$$ is not $0$.

If we prove that $p(c)\neq0 \forall c\in \mathbb{Q}^* $ we are done, since it means that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)/\mathbb{Q})\subseteq Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+c \beta)/\mathbb{Q})$ which implies $[\mathbb{Q} (\alpha+c\beta ):\mathbb{Q}]\geq4$.

But, expanding $p(x)$ we get that $$p(c)=0 \iff (\alpha+c\beta=0 \lor\alpha-c\beta=0)$$ which is impossible, since $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\neq\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.$\square$

Moreover I think that

> $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)/\mathbb{Q})\cong Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})\times Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\beta)/\mathbb{Q})$ is a sufficient condition.

*Proof.* by generalizing the above reasoning we get that $$p(c)=0\iff \exists i,j(i\neq j) s.t. (\sigma_j(\beta)-\sigma_i(\beta))c=\sigma_i(\alpha)-\sigma_j(\alpha)$$
which implies that $\sigma_j(\beta)-\sigma_i(\beta)$ and $\sigma_i(\alpha)-\sigma_j(\alpha)$ are both rational, and one of them is not $0$.
Say $\sigma_j(\beta)-\sigma_i(\beta)=q\in\mathbb{Q}^*$ then $\sigma_i^{-1}\sigma_j(\beta)=\beta+q$.

Then $$(\sigma_i^{-1}\sigma_j)^n, n\in\mathbb{N}$$
are all distinct elements of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\beta)/\mathbb{Q})$ which is finite, absurd.$\square$